# Declaring a var in Switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Can I declare a variable which is "<" or ">" than some number in the following switch-statement?

```
var a = 150
switch a {
case 10...50:
    print ("the value is 10 to 50")
    fallthrough
case 100...125:
    print ("the value is 100 to 125")
case 125...150:
    print ("the value is 125 to 150")
default:
    print ("the value is unknown")
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question 

Comment: What issue are facing in your implemented code after removing `fallthrough` ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use `where` clause to check for additional conditions in switch statement.

```
    var a = 150
    var x = 250
    switch a {
    case _ where a > x:
        print ("a is greater than x")
    case _ where a < x:
        print ("a is less than x")
    default:
        print ("a is equal to x")
    }
```

Or you can use `One sided range operator` to check if a number is greater or less than a particular number

```
        switch a {
        case ...50:
            print ("the value is less than 50")
        case 100...125:
            print ("the value is 100 to 125")
        case 125...:
            print ("the value greater than 125")
        default:
            print ("the value is unknown")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can declare a variable that is < or > some number in a switch statement, but I don't think that's what you mean.

I think you're really trying to ask if you can use < or > in the case evaluations. Yes, you can do that using a `where` clause.

So, you can do this, for example:

```
var a = 150
let b = 160
switch a {
    case 10...50 where b < a: print ("the value is 10 to 50 and b < a")
    case 100...125 where b == a: print ("the value is 100 to 125 and b == a")
    case 125...150 where b > a: print ("the value is 125 to 150 and b > a")
    default: print ("default")
}
```

That will print:

> the value is 125 to 150 and b > a

You can read more on Swift switch statements in the Swift documentation:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html